# Как отобразить сразу весь текст что есть внутри input value?

Tags: html, css, css3

```
<input type="text" name="atr" placeholder="Название" value="Модуль (плата) управления стиральной машины Whirlpool DOMINO AWE6415, AWE6515, AWE7515 и других... (Код: 480111104626)">
```

У меня есть очень длинный value и соответственно часть текста скрыта. (Нужно скролить в сторону чтобы прочитать далее). Как можно отобразить сразу весь текст в 2, 3 .. строки вниз.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В input никак, используйте textarea

Comment: в css есть свойство textoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://htmlbook.ru/html/textarea
- Вот что вам нужно, либо можно извратиться и изменить размер данного inputa с помощью атрибута size 
http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/size
- Ссылка на данный атрибут

Answer (score 1):

Да, **в input type="text" строка не переносится**. Также в нем нельзя обозначить троеточием конец строки.
Нужно несколько строк - заменить на textarea, без вариантов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]